# Composer ignores whitelist

Tags: php, composer-php

I have the following `require` sections in my `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.0",
    "henrikbjorn/phpspec-code-coverage": "~0.2",
    "satooshi/php-coveralls": "~0.6"
},
```

Now I want to use Travis-CI, for PHP 5.4 and 5.5, and hhvm. However, since hhvm does not support xdebug and therefore no code coverage, I need to disable code coverage for the hhvm build.

To do this, I need to exclude the code coverage installs. However, when I try to only install phpspec running `composer update phpspec/phpspec`, the other two dependencies get installed as well. Somehow Composer seems to ignore my whitelist.

This is my current `.travis.yml`:

```
language: php

php: [5.4, 5.5, hhvm]

install:
  - if [[ $TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION != 'hhvm' ]]; then composer update ; fi
  - if [[ $TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION == 'hhvm' ]]; then composer update phpspec/phpspec; fi

script:
  - bin/phpspec run --format=pretty
  - if [[ $TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION != 'hhvm' ]]; then bin/coveralls -v ; fi
```

How can I reach my goal using the whitelist feature, or is there another way to achieve this?

---

Note that I *do not* want to install `henrikbjorn/phpspec-code-coverage`, nor `satooshi/php-coveralls` *in the **hhvm** Travis build*. I *do* want to install them in the PHP 5.4 and 5.5 builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would follow a reversed logic of the accepted answer, since it is better to use a workaround when testing and not forcing yourself not to generate coverage locally.

```
language: php
php:
  - 5.4
  - 5.5
  - hhvm

script:
  - bin/phpspec run
  - bash -c 'if [ "$TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION" != "hhvm" ]; then bin/coveralls -v; fi;'

before_script:
  - bash -c 'if [ "$TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION" == "hhvm" ]; then composer remove "henrikbjorn/phpspec-code-coverage" --dev --no-update; fi;'
  - composer install --prefer-source
```

Comment: I did not know about the remove command, but this indeed is more natural.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need code coverage to work elsewhere, why not simply modify `.travis.yml` to require the code coverage using `composer require henrikbjorn/phpspec-code-coverage=~0.2`:

```
language: php

php: [5.4, 5.5, hhvm]

install:
    - if [[ $TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION != 'hhvm' ]]; then composer require henrikbjorn/phpspec-code-coverage=~0.2 ; fi

script:
    - bin/phpspec run --format=pretty
    - if [[ $TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION != 'hhvm' ]]; then bin/coveralls -v ; fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running

```
 php composer.phar self-update

 php composer.phar update --with-dependencies
```

According to the docs should ingnore what is in the whitelist

If you wish to update or chain update only a few packages please run the following

```
php composer.phar update "packagename" "packagename2"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, this does not address the fact that I'd like to _exclude_ packages from the install (i.e. only install `phpspec/phpspec`).

Comment: I have already tried that method, it didn't work, as stated in my question.

Comment: Appologies missed that in your question

Answer (score -1):

Try

`composer update --no-dev`

because when you run composer update it installs everything at "require-dev" by default

Comment: This will cause `phpspec` to not be installed either, which I obviously need in the Travis build.